# Azure AD and SAP-SF provisioning

Tags: azure, expression, integration-testing, provisioning, sap-successfactors

We are in the testing phase for the integration between Azure AD and SAP Success factors. In the provisioning process we have used the following mapping expression for creating unique UPN in Azure if two users have the same first name and last name, but from different company:
Append(Join(".", [firstName], [lastName]), Switch([companyName], "@x.onmicrosoft.com", "Contoso", "@contoso.com", "Fabricam", "@fabricam.com") )
How to update the expression to create unique UPN for the new user from the same company if he has the same first name and last name as an existing user in Azure AD?
I know that Use unique value expression works only for ActiveDirectory integration.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*SAP-SF has the unique naming format it has different attributes so according to that the Name format will make "Formal Name" field as "unique format"*

*Name format can be associated with Legal Entity so that configured name format.*

> First Name, Middle Name, Third Name, Last Name, Second Last Name, Birth Name, Initials, Prefix etc.

*Check these [Name format](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/02/13/name-format-in-successfactors-employee-central/) document as well as the [Attribute document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/sap-successfactors-attribute-reference#supported-successfactors-entities-and-attributes).*